# how to set mybatis mapper xml file in java code. and using hikari

Tags: java, mybatis, hikaricp

Error occurs because MAPPER cannot be found while MYBATIS and HIKARICP are being linked.

The MYBATIS-HIKARICP was set up in Java code. Perform normal operation except for HIKARICP.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setDefaultStatementTimeout(30);
configuration.setCacheEnabled(true);
configuration.addMappers("C:\ORACLE_MAAPER");

HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setMinimumIdle(dataBaseMap.get(pd.getKEY()));
config.setMaximumPoolSize(dataBaseMap.get(pd.getKEY()) * 2);
config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
config.setConnectionTimeout(300000);

config.setDriverClassName(setDriverName(pd.getDBMS()));
config.addDataSourceProperty("user", pd.getID());
config.addDataSourceProperty("password", pd.getPWD());
config.setJdbcUrl(setConnUrl(pd.getDBMS(), pd.getIP(), pd.getPORT(), pd.getNAME()));

configuration.setEnvironment(new Environment(pd.getKEY(), new JdbcTransactionFactory(), new HikariDataSource(config)));
```

It should operate normally and execute QUERY, but an error will occur. I also tried "file:///C:\MAPPER.xml".

Comment: Please also post the error message and/or stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.addMappers(String)` takes a package name as a parameter.

So instead of `C:\ORACLE_MAAPER` (BTW with typo apparently) you should specify the package where the mappers are located.